# Migrate Users to New iOS App

Tags: ios

Are there any best practices around migrating users from an old iOS app to an entirely new one? We have an existing app in the app store and need to prompt users download the new app (we moved to a native app from react native app).

Short of simply putting a download link in the new app when they open it, are there any other ideas for how to make the transition as smooth and seemless as possible?

Comment: What is the nature of your app? Do your users create any sort of profile, or maintain any personal settings? Do you deal with sensitive personal information? Does your app have any in-app purchases?

Answer (score 1):

You can just upload the new app with the same identifier to the App Store; the fact that it is built with another technology doesn't matter. The new app will be downloaded as 'just' an update. Migration of logins / user settings might be challenging, depending on how much you store only on the device and not on a server. In the case some users don't want to install updates, you might want to disable calls to your server from old versions of the app, and let them fail with another warning to install the new app version (but this isn't something you can retroactively apply to already distributed versions).